# java regex special character

Tags: java, regex, roman-numerals

I am using the following regular expression to find roman numerals in a string:

```
^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$
```

How can I change it to detect roman numerals preceded or followed by any special character except a period?

Comment: @trs Are preceding and following characters optional or mandatory? Do you expect exactly one on each side?

Comment: optional, it can either have one special character or none

Comment: This expression `[@!#%^*()_]?` matches zero or one of your special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this expression:

```
^[@!#%^*()_&-]?M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})[@!#%^*()_&-]?$
```

The `[@!#%^*()_&-]?` expression at the beginning and at the end match zero or one special characters from your list in the comment.

Comment: You missed `-` and `&`, it should be `[@!#%^*()_&-]`. Also note that `-` must be first or last and `^` can't be first or they take on their special character class meanings.

Comment: @veredesmarald You're right, I did miss these two! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You still need to put `-` at the start or the end. Currently it doesn't work because `_-&` defines a character range (in this case an invalid one since `&` is less than `_`).

Comment: @veredesmarald You're right again, I put the minus in the right place in the explanation part, but in the wrong place in the actual expression.